# Conditional expected value of mutlitple draws from uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, order-statistics

There are $m$ i.i.d. draws of $x$ made from a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. The $n$ ($n\leq m$) lowest draws are "winners", i.e. if we write $x_1\leq\ldots\leq x_n\ldots\leq x_m$, the draws $x_1$ to $x_n$ are "winning draws".

Now player/draw $i$ learns his $x_i$ and the fact that he is a winner, i.e. $i\in[1,n]$. What is the expected value of the remaining $(n-1)$ winning draws, given $i$'s knowledge of his own draw and the fact that he is a winner (but not knowing his "rank"/position among the winners).

---

**EDIT:** With the help of the comments below, this is what I have managed to do (credits to the commentators!):

- The unconditional expected value of the winning draws is $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{i}{1+m}=\frac{n+1}{2(m+1)}$.
- Obviously, the unconditional cdf is given by $F(x)=x$ for $x\in[0,1]$.
- $i$ can be the 1st, 2nd, ... nth of the winners. For each rank, compute the expected value of the remaining $n-1$ winners (distributed below/above him, depending on $i$'s rank) and weight it by the probability of this rank.
- The expected value of the remaining winners, conditional on $x_i$ and the knowledge that $i$ is a "winner", can hence be computed by (incomplete and possibly wrong!):

\begin{alignat*}{3}
\frac{1}{n-1}\bigg(%
 &(1-x_i)^{m-1}   &\cdot\binom{m-1}{0} &[(1-1)\frac{x_i}{2} &+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(x_i+(1-x_i)E[x_{(k)}^{m-1}])]\\
+ &(1-x_i)^{m-2}x_i^1  &\cdot\binom{m-1}{1} &[(2-1)\frac{x_i}{2} &+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}(x_i+(1-x_i)E[x_{(k)}^{m-2}])]\\
+ &\ldots\\
+ &(1-x_i)^{m-j-2}x_i^{j-1} &\cdot\binom{m-1}{j-1} &[(j-1)\frac{x_i}{2} &+\sum_{k=1}^{n-j}(x_i+(1-x_i)E[x_{(k)}^{m-j}])]\\
+ &\ldots\\
+ &(1-x_i)^{m-n-1}x_i^{n-1} &\cdot\binom{m-1}{n-1} &[(n-1)\frac{x_i}{2} &+\sum_{k=1}^{n-n}(x_i+(1-x_i)E[x_{(k)}^{m-n}])]%
\bigg)
\end{alignat*}

---

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Is the above correct? For example, am I missing a normalisation?
2. Is it correct that if in addition $i$ also knew his "rank", rather than using the summation above, he would only consider the respective summand indicating the correct position. (From the comments, this seems to be correct.) How does this change a potential normalisation?
3. Is it correct that
   $$ E[x_{(k)}^{m-j}]=\frac{k}{m+1-j} $$
   in the equation above, with $x_{(k)}^{m-j}$ being (if I understand it correctly) the k-th lowest out of $m-j$ iid draws?
4. If I was also interested in the expected *square* of the other "winners" (not the square of the expected other winners), I would need to modify the formula above such that:

   - replace $(j-1)\frac{x_i}{2}$ by
     $$E[\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}x_k^2|x_k\sim U(0,x_i), \text{ iid}]=\frac{x_i^2 (2j-1)}{6j}$$
   - and $E[x_{(k)}^{m-j}]$ by
     $$E[(x_{(k)}^{m-j})^2]=(\frac{k}{m+1-j})^2$$

---

Also, should I delete my lengthy (and wrong) comments below? Should I make this question more "canonical" (and if so, how)?

Comment: If the rank $i$ and the position $x$ are both known, the remaining winning sample is made of $i-1$ values i.i.d. uniform on $(0,x)$ and of the $n-i$ lowest positions in an i.i.d. sample of size $m-i$ uniform on $(x,1)$. Thus the conditional mean $w$ of the remaining winning sample is $$E(w\mid x,i)=(i-1)\frac{x}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-i}(x+(1-x)E(x_{(k)}^{m-i}))=(i-1)\frac{x}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-i}\left(x+(1-x)\frac{k}{m-i+1}\right).$$

Comment: The general question can be reformulated, maybe more canonically, as follows. Let $(X_k^{(m)})_{1\leqslant k\leqslant m}$ denote an ordered sample uniform on $(0,1)$ and $W_n^m=\{X_k^{(m)}\mid1\leqslant k\leqslant n\}$, then, what is $$E(X_1^{(m)}+\cdots+X_n^{(m)}-x\mid x\in W_n^m)\ ?$$

Comment: @Did, is this really the same? Your expression, I would presume, could be rewritten 

$$
E(X_1^{(m)}+\cdots+X_n^{(m)})-x|_{x\in W_n^m} = \frac{n+1)}{2(m+1)}-x,
$$

i.e. we would be considering the $n$ lowest draws (in expectation) and substract one realisation ($x$) rather than only considering the remaining ($n-1$) other lowest draws (in expectation). Is this really the same?

Comment: @Bernd: I'm not sure how to interpret the notation in your comment, but if I understand correctly what you mean, it's not the same thing, since you've dropped the condition, whereas the expectation in Did's comment is conditional. I believe Did's reformulation is correct. (I'm not sure how much more canonical it is though. :-)

Comment: @Bernd Yes. Really.

Comment: Your expressions for the case of unknown rank are almost right, but you're missing binomial coefficients $\binom{m-1}k$ for the ways of choosing the $k$ out $m-1$ draws below $x$. That leads to an incomplete sum over the lower index of a binomial coefficient, for which there's no closed form. Note also that you need to divide by the sum of the probabilities to get the conditional expectation. (By the way, your expressions are for a general distribution; if you're only interested in the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$, you can use $F(x_i)=x_i$.)

Comment: @Did: I agree with your expression for the case of known rank, but I think in the question $i$ was meant to be the number of the player, not the rank of the draw.

Comment: @Bernd: Regarding your question about the case of fixed rank: Yes, you'd then use just one of the lines, but in that case dividing through by the sum of the probabilities would simply cancel the probability, so you'd really just be calculating the expected value in that line; this is what Did did above.

Comment: @joriki: thanks for the explanation, which I will work through. Regarding the no-closed-form-solution: you were posting an answer earlier on involving the incomplete Beta function, which now seems to be deleted. Is that because it was incorrect? If not, would you mind reposting it? I still don't quite know how to get to an answer even if it is not in a closed form...

Comment: @Bernd: Yes, unfortunately that answer was incorrect, because I'd wrongly assumed that $x$ is equally likely to be any of the first $n$ order statistics. To get the answer, multiply your lines by the binomial coefficients given above, fill in the dots using Did's expression for the expected value for known rank (taking into account that he repurposed $i$ to denote the rank), add up all the lines and normalise by the sum of the probabilities (including the binomial coefficients).

Comment: I didn't post this as an answer because that tends to reduce attention for the question and someone might find a closed form after all; but if you like I can write it out as an answer.

Comment: @joriki: Many thanks for the walkthrough! Could you possibly confirm whether my use of your comments is correct below? I would then follow your advice and hope for a closed-form solution to emerge...
Just to be sure I am on the correct track: is it correct that  
a) $E[x_{(k)}^{m-j}]=\frac{k}{m+1-j}]$?  
b) if I was also interested in the expected _square_ of the average of the other "winners", I would need to change $(j-1)\frac{x_i}{2}$ to $E[\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}x_k^2|x_k\sim U(0,x_i),\text{ iid}]=\frac{x_i^2 (2j-1)}{6j}$ and $E[x_{(k)}^{m-j}]$ to $E[(x_{(k)}^{m-j})^2]=(\frac{k}{m+1-j})^2$?

Comment: With my current solution being:
\begin{alignat*}{3}
 &(1-x_i)^{m-1}   &\cdot\binom{m-1}{0} &[(1-1)\frac{x_i}{2} &+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(x_i-(1-x_i)E[x_{(k)}^{m-1}])]\\
+ &(1-x_i)^{m-2}x_i^1  &\cdot\binom{m-1}{1} &[(2-1)\frac{x_i}{2} &+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}(x_i-(1-x_i)E[x_{(k)}^{m-2}])]\\
+ &\ldots\\
+ &(1-x_i)^{m-j-2}x_i^{j-1} &\cdot\binom{m-1}{j-1} &[(j-1)\frac{x_i}{2} &+\sum_{k=1}^{n-j}(x_i-(1-x_i)E[x_{(k)}^{m-j}])]\\
+ &\ldots\\
+ &(1-x_i)^{m-n-1}x_i^{n-1} &\cdot\binom{m-1}{n-1} &[(n-1)\frac{x_i}{2} &+\sum_{k=1}^{n-n}(x_i-(1-x_i)E[x_{(k)}^{m-n}])]
\end{alignat*}

Comment: Hi, sorry I didn't respond earlier. On your questions in the edit: 1) Yes, you're missing a normalisation. You're multiplying by the unconditional probabilities; the conditional probabilities are proportional to them but sum to $1$, so you need to divide by the sum of the probabilities. 2) Yes, correct, and the normalisation would then divide by the "sum" of a single probability, cancelling it, so in this case you have only the expected value. 3) Correct. 4) The expectation of the square isn't the square of the expectation (in fact their difference is the variance).

Comment: By the way, you can get parentheses, brackets and other paired delimiters to adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: @joriki: thank you! 1) just to be sure: the probabilities are
$$ (1-x_i)^{m-j-2}x_i^{j-1}\binom{m-1}{j-1} $$,
i.e. including the Binomial coefficient? I would sum these up over $j$ and that's the normalisation by which I have to divide?  
  
4) I have (hopefully) corrected my question (sorry for the confusion), I of course was not interested in the square of the expectation (for which I could just square the result?) but in the expectation of the square. Is my approach correct here?  
  
Many thanks for the help! Feel free to turn it into an answer yourself so that I can accept it!

Comment: 1) That's correct. 4) I think that was a misunderstanding. The passage you edited was fine; in fact it was clearer before; in the new formulation it's not clear what the square of the winners is. I was referring to the fact that you simply squared the expected value $k/(m+1-j)$; that's the square of the expectation where you want the expectation of the square.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry, I'd noticed the sign error but forgot to mention it.

Comment: @joriki: I never came to accept an answer here. My current solution to the exp. average of the remaining winning draws, knowing $x_i,i\leq n$, is as follows:
$$
\frac{1}{(n-1)\sum_{j=1}^n (1-x_i)^{m-j}x_i^{j-1}\binom{m-1}{j-1}}\sum_{j=1}^n\binom{m-1}{j-1}(1-x_i)^{m-j}x_i^{j-1}\left((j-1)\frac{x_i}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-j}(x_i+\frac{k(1-x_i)}{m-j+1})\right)
$$
(there is a mistake in my comment above, where I wrote $(1-x_i)^{m-j-2}$) Would you consider this correct? If so, do you want to post it as an answer which I can accept? I did not want to take these credits myself given your walthrough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above, this is what I've come to:

There are $m$ i.i.d. draws of X from $U(0,1)$, with $x_{(1)}\leq\ldots\leq x_{(n)}\leq\ldots\leq x_{(m)}$ being the order statistics. Given some $x_{(i)}=x_i, i\in N=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, I want to compute the expected average of the $(n-1)$ remaining lowest draws - conditional on knowing $x_i, i\in N$, but **not** knowing the rank $(i)$ itself! That is, I know that the draw $x_i$ is among the $n$ lowest, but not its precise order.

With the help of the comments, the solution seems to be that this expectation equals

$$
\underbrace{\frac{1}{(n-1)}}_{1.}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^n \binom{m-1}{j-1}\left(1-x_i\right)^{m-j}x_i^{j-1}}}_{2.}\cdot\sum_{j=1}^n\underbrace{\binom{m-1}{j-1}(1-x_i)^{m-j}x_i^{j-1}}_{3.}\underbrace{\left((j-1)\frac{x_i}{2}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-j}(x_i+\frac{k(1-x_i)}{m-j+1})\right)}_{4.}
$$

where the terms represent

1. average ($n-1$ items)
2. normalisation
3. probability of $x_i$ being order position $j$
4. conditional expectation of the remaining $(n-1)$ samples if $x_i$ is order position $j$

If anyone can confirm this (I posted it as a comment previously), I'd be very grateful. Also, if one of the commenters who helped me with the solution would like to post this as an answer themselves, I am more than happy to mark it as accepted!